# How do I download csv changes from my Heroku

Tags: csv, github, heroku, streamlit

I made a heroku app with streamlit and I used two csv files to save changes. The app is a schedule for group plans, the changes people introduce in the schedule are visible online but when i check my git repository it is not actualized.
How can I download the modificated csv files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git repository stores the application source code, which gets deployed to Heroku.

At runtime you application use the **Heroku local storage** when saving files (not the git repository). You need to download/fetch the CSV files from the application.

Given that Heroku file system is ephemeral (local files are removed when the application restarts) it is not a good idea to persist data on the local filesystem, but rather using an external storage.

You can check out some options in [HerokuFiles](https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuFiles) GitHub repository. If you want the CSV files to be stored with the application source code you can use [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to perform a commit.

Comment: I tried the second option but I found that streamlit has not the github package installed so i my code does not run.

Comment: SOLVED, I added the package in a diferente stcript and when i upload everything to heroku, as heroku imports packages itselv I solved the problem.

Now I have to have automatic deploy enabled in heroku but that is not a problem, THANK YOU REALLY MUCH

Comment: Excellent. I am not sure you want autodeployment enabled as you will commit changes in the Github repository from the app, triggering a redeployment.